# Does adding bend points to NiFi affect system performance?

Tags: apache-nifi

There are some differing opinions in my office, so asking to see if anyone knows:
If we add multiple bend points to our NiFi flow, will they adversely affect system performance?

I know they can make a canvas more visually easy to follow, but we have one person who uses them A LOT when designing a flow (like between every single processor), and another person who keeps saying it's a problem.

So does anyone know if they are a good idea, should only be used in moderation, or try not to use them at all?

Comment: They don't affect performance of the data flow itself, but a busy canvas can make your browser laggy when you view the UI - this has been improved a bit recently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bend points on Connections do not affect the performance of the data flow. They are used solely to help make the flow more readable as the number of components on the canvas grows. Further, the connection label can then be placed over any desired bend point.

Comment: Matt's answer is correct concerning NiFi system performance. The actual canvas is drawn within your browser, where there might be some slight performance issues for *you*. There was a bug in Chromium 92 that caused major issues displaying a canvas with many connections, but that has been fixed since 93.